# GraphQL and Next.js TypeError when setting up a dynamic route with getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, next.js, graphql

I'm using Next.js, Apollo and GraphQL to fetch data from GraphCMS — and have successfully managed to do that. But now I'm trying to set up a dynamic route `[slug].js` inside my `posts` page (that is inside the `pages` folder) and I'm having a hard figuring it out. There are many posts here about it but I wasn't able to follow along and fix my issue.

These are my dependencies in case that's useful:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.6.9",
    "framer-motion": "^7.3.6",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-request": "^5.0.0",
    "next": "^12.3.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
```

And this is my `[slug].js` file.

```
import client from "../../apolloClient";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export default function BlogPostPage({ posts }) {
  return <div>{posts.title}</div>;
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query {
        posts {
          slug
        }
      }
    `,
  });

  const { posts } = data;
  const paths = posts.map((post) => ({
    params: { slug: [post.slug] },
  }));
  console.log(paths);
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}

export async function getStaticProps(params) {
  const slug = params.slug[0];

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: gql`
      query PostBySlug($slug: String!) {
        posts(where: { slug: $slug }) {
          content {
            raw
          }
          date
          id
          slug
          title
          coverImage {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: { slug },
  });

  const { posts } = data;
  const post = posts[0];
  console.log(post);

  return { props: { post } };
}
```

The error I get is `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` caused by `const slug = params.slug[0];`.

My `console.log(paths)` shows this:

```
[{params: {slug: [Array] } }, { params: {slug: [Array] } } ]
```

I've noticed changing the file name from `[...slug].js` to `[slug].js]` changes the error I get to `Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /posts/[slug]`. In this scenario I tried to do `params: {slug: [post.slug].toString()` but then I get the same `typeError` as before.

Any ideas of what could be happening and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: look this line defined string! type ($slug: String!)

Comment: Hey @Bryro, thanks for replying! Unfortunately I don't quite understand what you mean. Changing or removing the line `query PostBySlug($slug: String!)` doesn't affect the type error caused by `const slug = params.slug[0];`. Would you be so kind to provide a more in depth explanation of what you meant?

Comment: If you want to use the route `[slug].js` the `params.slug` value has to be a string. Replace `{ params: { slug: [post.slug] }` with `{ params: { slug: post.slug }`. If `post.slug` is not a string then you have to convert it to one.